# JSTL loop through multidimensional hashmap

Tags: java, loops, jsp, hashmap, jstl

This is my java code which creates a multidimensional hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> data = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

for (App app : apps) {
    String randomVar = "";

    data.put(String.valueOf(app.getId()), new HashMap<String, String>());
    data.get(String.valueOf(app.getId())).put("name", app.getName());
    data.get(String.valueOf(app.getId())).put("info", randomVar);
}
```

This is my `.jsp` file:

```
<c:forEach items="${data}" var="items">
    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="overview">
                <a href="/goto/${items.key}" class="minimal" title="Switch to: ${item.name}">
                    ${item.randomVar}
                    <span>${item.name}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Unfortunately, I can't make the loop in the jsp file work. The problem is with the second loop. I can't reach the variables. Whatever I try, I get errors like `Don't know how to iterate over supplied 'items' in <forEach>` or that `items.name` doesn't exist and so on. How can I properly loop the hashmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `items="${items.value}`?

Comment: That gives me this error: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 
'name' not found on type java.util.HashMap$Node`

Comment: @Jordy yes, it's also `${item.key}` instead of `${item.name}` and `${item.value.name}` and `${item.value.info}`

Comment: @Jordy no, `${item.key} ` will have 'name' and 'info', `${item.value}` will have app.getName() and randomVar (but of course, `${item.name}` and `${item.randomVar}` don't exist).